# how to extract multiple HTML element's value in Jmeter?

Tags: html, jmeter, css-selectors, functional-testing

As per my knowledge, should I use multiple CSS extractors for extracting each value?

Here is HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    Redirecting

    <form id="pageform" action="abc.shtml" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="key1" value="abc" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="appversion" value="4.0.0" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="resURL" value="https://test.com" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="sessionValidity" value="2021-07-16T07:35:25Z" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="allow" value="false" />
                </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function formAutoSubmit () {
            var frm = document.getElementById("pageform");
            frm.submit();
        }
    window.onload = formAutoSubmit;
    </script>
</body>
```

And I have to use name and value in the next sampler from this respone.

Looking for help on this. Let me know if you need any more info on this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all [value](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) attributes of the [hidden input fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) in a single CSS Selector Extractor by using `input[type=hidden]` CSS selector:

[image]

So if you configure CSS Selector Extractor like this:

[image]

You will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) created:

[image]

More information:

- [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)